# SSL Broken PIPE in Android 2.3 HTTPS call over a Proxy

Tags: android, ssl, https, proxy

I've been through every related post I can find trying to get to the bottom of this and am no clearer - hoping someone can put me out of my misery…

I am trying to get Android 2.3 to POST  over HTTPS via a Proxy. This code works perfectly on 2.2 through a proxy, and perfectly on both 2.2 and 2.3 using HTTPS when not going through a proxy, and in all cases (2.2 and 2.3)  i can GET over HTTPS through a proxy.  Its just 2.3 POST using HTTPS through a proxy that seems to be the issue.  I get the dreaded "broken pipe" error. The error is thrown when I try and read the inputstream response from the connection - presumably because the TCP socket has been closed underneath my stream. I've tried everything I can think of, including using Connection and Proxy-connection headers (setting to both close and keep-alive) and setting big readTimeout numbers (30 seconds). From my relentless googling, I can see there are known issues with SSL on Android 2.3, but I can't seem to find anything that suggests why the POST might be an issue. Wireshark has yielded some results, but given this is SSL if just a little bit tricky to get to the issue.

Has anyone seem this. I'm using HttpsURLConnection as various posts suggest this is more stable that AndroidHttpClient. Here is my code…any help at all invaluable. Thanks

```
urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(factory);     
urlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new AllowAllHostnameVerifier() );

String dateText = "{\"loopParam\":\"" + String.valueOf(d.getHours()) + ":" +   String.valueOf(d.getMinutes()) + ":" + String.valueOf(d.getSeconds())  + "\"}";
                txtOutput.setText("Sending " +     String.valueOf(dateText.length() ) + " bytes of JSON to /pulse/loop" );

urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Proxy-connection", "Keep-Alive");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(30000);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                DataOutputStream dataOut = new     DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                dataOut.writeBytes(dateText);
                dataOut.flush();

BufferedReader bufIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String sResponse;
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

         //bufIn is null as error as closed urlcConnection
            while ((sResponse = bufIn.readLine()) != null) {
                s = s.append(sResponse);
            }
```

Error details:
    08-May-12 09:09:51 SsliferSnifferActivity Connecting through proxy INFO

```
08-May-12 09:09:54 SsliferSnifferActivity javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x2d42b8: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_write(Native Method)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.write(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:837)
at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:80)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.writeRequestHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:799)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1028)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:726)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:110)
at uk.co.flurrished.sslifersniffer.SslifersnifferActivity.makeRequest(SslifersnifferActivity.java:236)
at uk.co.flurrished.sslifersniffer.SslifersnifferActivity.access$2(SslifersnifferActivity.java:148)
at uk.co.flurrished.sslifersniffer.SslifersnifferActivity$2.onClick(SslifersnifferActivity.java:76)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3822)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT : This looks like it is being caused by the server raising a 400 (Bad Request) and closing the pipe. What is it about ANdroid 2.3 that is adding extra content when routed through a proxy that causes the 400?

Comment: Independently of this issue, you shouldn't use `new AllowAllHostnameVerifier()` (or a trust manager that accepts anything if this is also the case): this makes your connection vulnerable to MITM attacks.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, yes, this is something I put in place to eliminate cert issues, but yes, couldn't use in production...thanks

Comment: @MikeB I would caution you against using it even in development. Solve the problem. I have a suspicion nearing a certainty that many of these 'workarounds' have actually migrated into production. Specifically, not verifying the hostname properly is a violation of the HTTPS protocol, and trusting all certificates makes the SSL/TLS protocol insecure.

Comment: Hey Mike,  did you ever find a solution or workaround for this? We're experiencing something similar here on various Android versions, using a proxy over ssl (pound/varnish).

Comment: Hi John N, yes, should have posted back but didn't as I had to change tack. Basically, in the form this question is in, I couldn't get this to work. HttpUrlConnection seemed completely unreliable over the proxy using SSL on 2.3. I went with the Apache HttpClient libs, and despite what I've heard about them being the wrong choice for Android, they worked beautifully. I would recommend that lib over HttpUrlConnection. I'm not able to get at the code at the moment, but let me know if you want me to post my solution and I'll certainly do so.

Answer (score 2):

'Broken pipe' has exactly one meaning. You have written to a connection that has already been closed by the other end. Are you sure the peer is really speaking SSL?

Comment: hi, yes, because outside a proxy is works fine, and it works fine with Android 2.2 (all the time, proxy or not), so I'm happy the implementation is correct, just that something (presumably Android) closes the pipe  after the POST despite Keep-Alives. If it was the server closing the pipe, we'd see Android 2.2 fail alongside failures outside the proxy. Is it possible Android 2.3 isn't setting length correctly, but then I don't see why the proxy would care as its using CONNECT?

Comment: @MikeB I agree, I don't see why the proxy would care. I can't follow the rest of your comment.